# Integrating non-Angular code?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm developing a Cordova/PhoneGap app, and I'm using the $cordovaPush plugin (wrapped for PushPlugin) to handle push notifications.

The code looks something like this:

```
var androidConfig = {
                    "senderID" : "mysenderID",
                    "ecb"      : "onNotification"
                }

                $cordovaPush.register(androidConfig).then(function(result) {
                    console.log('Cordova Push Reg Success');
                    console.log(result);            
                }, function(error) {
                    console.log('Cordova push reg error');
                    console.log(error);
                });
```

The "ecb" function must be defined with window scope, ie:

```
window.onNotification = function onNotification(e)...
```

This function handles incoming events. I'd obviously like to handle incoming events in my angular code - how can I integrate the two so that my onNotification function can access my scope/rootScope variables?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you'll wrap your 3rd party library in a `service` or a `factory`, but in the spirit of answering your particular scenario...

Here's one possibility:

```
angular.module('myApp').
   controller('myController', function($scope, $window) {
     $window.onNotification = function() {
       $scope.apply(function() {
         $scope.myVar = ...updates...
       });
     };
   });
```

A couple of things to notice:

- Try to use `$window`, not `window`.  It's a good habit to get into as it will help you with testability down the line.  Because of the internals of Cordova, you might actually need to use `window`, but I doubt it.
- The function that does all of the work is buried inside of `$scope.apply`.  **If you forget to do this, then any variables you update will not be reflected in the view** until the digest cycle runs again (if ever).
- Although I put my example in a controller, you might put yours inside of a handler.  If its an angular handler (`ng-click`, for example), you might think that because the `ng-click` has an implicit $apply wrapping the callback, your `onNotification` function is not called at that time, so you still need to do the `$apply`, as above.
- ...seriously... don't forget the apply.  :-)  When I'm debugging people's code, it's the number one reason why external libraries are not working.  We all get bit at least once by this.

Answer (score 0):

Define a kind of a mail controller in body and inside that controller use the `$window` service.

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="MainController">
     <!-- other markup .-->
</body>
```

JS:

```
yourApp.controller("BaseController", ["$scope", "$window", function($scope, $window) {

    $window.onNotification = function(e) {
        // Use $scope or any Angular stuff
    }
}]);
```